# How do I create a dictionary in OCaml that associates to each element of the first list the number of its occurences in the second list?

Tags: string, list, dictionary, types, ocaml

I have two lists, ["0","1"] and ["0","1","0"], and I want to get a list, [(0,2),(1,1)], - which associates to each element of the first list the number of its occurrences in the second list. I tried this:

```
let partialSolution = 
List.map(
    fun x -> 
        let subsubList = List.for_all  (fun y -> (String.compare x y)=0) ) ("0"::("1"::("0"::[]))) in
 (x, List.length ( List.filter ( fun z -> z = true) subsubList ) ) 
) ;;
```

, but it's not good: it gives me these errors:

```
# let partialSolution = 
# List.map(
#     fun x -> 
#         let subsubList = List.for_all  (fun y -> (String.compare x y)=0) )
File "", line 4, characters 73-74:
Error: Syntax error: operator expected.
#  ("0"::("1"::("0"::[]))) in
File "", line 4, characters 99-101:
Error: Syntax error
#  (x, List.length ( List.filter ( fun z -> z = true) subsubList ) ) 
# )
File "", line 6, characters 0-1:
Error: Syntax error
#  ;;
File "", line 6, characters 2-4:
Error: Syntax error
```

I would like to understand how I can fix this - I am a total newbie to OCaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a bit overzealous with the parentheses. The syntax error is caused by an extra closing parentheses after `(fun y -> ...)`.

But you'll still have a type error, since `List.for_all` returns a `bool`, `true` if all items satisfy the predicate and `false` otherwise. It seems you want to use `List.map` here instead.

You also don't need to surround every use of `::` with parentheses. `("0"::"1"::"0"::[])` is fine, but you can also just reduce this to a simple list literal: `["0"; "1"; "0"]`. Additionally, `z = true` is equivalent to `z`, though perhaps slightly less readable.

This compiles. I haven't checked whether it actually does what you want though:

```
let partialSolution = 
    List.map
        begin fun x -> 
            let subsubList =
                List.map
                    (fun y -> String.compare x y = 0)
                    ["0"; "1"; "0"]
            in
            (x, List.length (List.filter (fun z -> z) subsubList)) 
        end
```

Also, if you're using 4.03 or higher you can use `String.equal`, and if you're using 4.08 you can use `Fun.id` instead of the ad hoc lambda functions:

```
let partialSolution = 
    List.map
        begin fun x -> 
            let subsubList =
                List.map (String.equal x) ["0"; "1"; "0"]
            in
            (x, List.length (List.filter Fun.id subsubList)) 
        end
```

Or instead of dealing with an intermediate `bool list`, you could use `List.fold_left` to do a count directly:

```
let partialSolution = 
    List.map
        begin fun x -> 
            let count =
                List.fold_left
                    (fun count y ->
                        if String.compare x y = 0 then
                            count + 1
                        else
                            count)
                    0 ["0"; "1"; "0"]
            in
            (x, count) 
        end
```

Comment: I have an additional question: what is Fun.id precisely? I cannot find the documentation about it, but I presume it is the call to the environment of the function and the id is the reference to some value, but what is it?

Comment: It's the identity function, a one argument function that returns exactly what it's given. Documented here: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Fun.html

Comment: The third solution you proposed - with List.fold_left - is very elegant!

Comment: Folds usually are, but they can be a a little bit hard to grasp and see opportunities for at first. Many languages call it `reduce` instead, which might be a more helpful name.

Comment: In fact reduce is a more helpful name for this procedure! I've heard about reduce in fact - it's powerful.

Comment: If the first list is large then you do many passes over the second list, which becomes rather slow. For larger inputs using a Hashtbl to count elements might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Presented as an alternative: using a map to efficiently calculate the result. First we create a map where the elements of the first list are keys bound to `0`.

Then we fold over the second list, updating the values in the map *if* it's an element that's a key in the map already. The `None -> None` case in the pattern match handles doing nothing if the element in the second list isn't in the first list.

We can then use `StrMap.bindings` to get the corresponding association list.

Runtime complexity would be O(len(lst2) * log(len(lst1))).

```
module StrMap = Map.Make (String)

let count lst1 lst2 =
  let map = 
    List.fold_left 
      (fun m x -> StrMap.add x 0 m) 
      StrMap.empty 
      lst1 
  in
  lst2
  |> List.fold_left 
       (fun m x -> 
          StrMap.update 
            x 
            (function 
             | None -> None 
             | Some c -> Some (c + 1)) 
            m) 
       map
  |> StrMap.bindings
```

Testing this:

```
# count ["0"; "1"] ["0"; "1"; "0"; "2"];;
- : (string * int) list = [("0", 2); ("1", 1)]
```